# How to get the full gold chip

Tags: mega-man-x3

After you unlock the boots, the charge buster, the helmet and the armor, you can find an additional upgrade for **one** of these power ups.

How do you get the gold chip that upgrades **all 4** body parts ?

Comment: retagged as per your request

Comment: @JohnoBoy Thanks ! I'll try to get out a few mmx3 questions for the tag to stay alive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to get the Golden Chip in Megaman X3.
>
> First off you need to have all items including:
>
> All 8 Hearts All 4 Sub Tanks All 4 Ride Armors And all 4 Body Upgrades
>   EXCEPT the any of the Chips
>
> Now go to Doppler's Lab 1 and go all the way through the level until
>   you reach the part with the falling spike balls. Now make sure you
>   have FULL health and jump down the hole on the left. Make sure to
>   cling to the left wall and near the bottom you will fall through an
>   invisible wall. Finally there should be a redish pink capsule. Hop in
>   and when you come back out you are Golden.
>
> You now have all 4 Body Chips in one. So you can now dash twice in mid
>   air, take enven less damage, recover health when you stand still, and
>   a new power has been added to you ability list.

Source: [This YouTube Walkthrough](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2NEhPaoF71U)